# LimeSDR Mini + Raspberry Pi 3 B+ Transmission problem

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio, transmitter

I am new at this. I would like to transmit an audio signal cleanly using WBFM but I see two signal peaks occur around my fundamental frequency when I start transmitting.

In this case I am using a 1Khz tone but also when I send a song, at high frequencies the song is distorted due to the two signal peaks that appear.

How can I fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the problem exactly? It looks pretty good, apart from maybe more 3rd harmonic than expected in the decoded audio

Comment: What would be the reason that these harmonics are being produced and how could I avoid them? I do not know if it's a software or hardware problem. I would like to be able to transmit in a clean way.

Comment: hint: the operating system you're running on the pi has a screenshot functionality, and so does the GNU Radio companion; don't use your camera to take a picture of your screen, but use your network to copy the screenshot file from your Pi to your computer.

Comment: Also: don't use the WX gui widgets. We're in the process of removing them from GNU Radio, since we can't support them anymore, they don't work on many platforms, and use far more CPU to do the same job as their Qt siblings.

Comment: Harmonics can happen by any non-linearity. You might be overdriving your RTL dongle with too much input power. You might be overdriving your Lime. There might be completely other things wrong.

Comment: Thanks Marcus Müller! Could you give me some advice to identify if I am overloading the Lime or RTL-SDR? To discard possible reasons of non-linearity

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I would like to transmit an audio signal cleanly using WBFM but I see two signal peaks occur around my fundamental frequency when I start transmitting. How could I solve this? In this case I am using a 1Khz tone but when I send a song, at high frequencies the song is distorted due to the two signal peaks that appear.

Comment: Please rewrite the original question in the form of a question